# How can I pass a Lambda of x => bool, to a method, and Use it is a Linq Where?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I pass a Lambda predicate, to a method, and use it is a Linq Where expression?

**Edit for Clarity:**

I am trying to add the following functionality to `StateOverTime<T>`

```
var instanstOfStateOverTimeOfTypeTestType1 = new StatesOverTime<TestType1>();
var result = instanstOfStateOverTimeOfTypeTestType1.TotalTimeWhere(x => x.IsRunning == false)
```

with `x` being of `T` and not `StateOverTime<T>`.

**/Edit**

On this line `var results = States.Where(predicate);` I receive the following syntax error

> `IList<StateOverTime<T>>` does not contain a definition for 'Where' and
>   the best extension method overload
>   `ParallelEnumerable.Where<T>(ParallelQuery<T>, Func<T, bool>)`
>   requires a receiver of type `ParallelQuery<T>`

Here is my .Net Fiddler for this

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/3AyPln

For completeness here is my Sample Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackQuestionLamda
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var DataStartTime = DateTime.Now;


            var testData = new StatesOverTime<TestType1>();
            testData.States.Add(
                new StateOverTime<TestType1>() {
                    State = new TestType1() { IsRunning = true },
                    Start = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(0),
                    End = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(5)
                });
            testData.States.Add(
                new StateOverTime<TestType1>()
                {
                    State = new TestType1() { IsRunning = false },
                    Start = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(5),
                    End = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(10)
                });
            testData.States.Add(
                new StateOverTime<TestType1>()
                {
                    State = new TestType1() { IsRunning = true },
                    Start = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(10),
                    End = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(15)
                });


            var testData2 = new StatesOverTime<TestType2>();
            testData2.States.Add(
                new StateOverTime<TestType2>()
                {
                    State = new TestType2() { IsRunning = true, IsAlarmed = false },
                    Start = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(0),
                    End = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(5)
                });
            testData2.States.Add(
                new StateOverTime<TestType2>()
                {
                    State = new TestType2() { IsRunning = false, IsAlarmed = true, StatusCode = 99 },
                    Start = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(5),
                    End = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(10)
                });
            testData2.States.Add(
                new StateOverTime<TestType2>()
                {
                    State = new TestType2() { IsRunning = true, IsAlarmed = false },
                    Start = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(10),
                    End = DataStartTime.AddMinutes(15)
                });


            var TotalTimeNotRunning = testData.TotalTimeWhere(x => x.IsRunning == false);

            var TotalTimeIsAlarmed = testData2.TotalTimeWhere(x => x.IsAlarmed == true);

        }
    }


    public class StateOverTime<T>
    {
        public TimeSpan TimeSpan { get => End - Start; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public T State { get; set; }

    }

    public class StatesOverTime<T>
    {
        public IList<StateOverTime<T>> States = new List<StateOverTime<T>>();

        public TimeSpan TotalTimeWhere(Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            //var results = States.Where(function);
            var results = States.Where(predicate);

            var blah = new TimeSpan(results.Select(x => x.TimeSpan).Sum(x => x.Ticks));

            return blah;
        }
        public double PercentDownTime;
    }

    public class TestType1
    {
        public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestType2
    {
        public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
        public bool IsAlarmed { get; set; }
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Func<T, bool> should be Func<StateOverTime<T>, bool>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `States` is a collection of `StateOverTime<T>` and your `predicate` takes `Func<T, bool>`. The types just don't match.

You need to apply `predicate` to `State` property of collection items, instead of collection items itself:

```
public class StatesOverTime<T>
{
    public IList<StateOverTime<T>> States = new List<StateOverTime<T>>();

    public TimeSpan TotalTimeWhere(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        //var results = States.Where(function);
        var results = States.Where(state => predicate(state.State));

        var blah = new TimeSpan(results.Select(x => x.TimeSpan).Sum(x => x.Ticks));

        return blah;
    }
    public double PercentDownTime;
}
```

Or you can use `StateOverTime<T>` as a predicate, if you would like to be able to use properties of `StateOverTime` in your queries:

```
public class StatesOverTime<T>
{
    public IList<StateOverTime<T>> States = new List<StateOverTime<T>>();

    public TimeSpan TotalTimeWhere(Func<StateOverTime<T>, bool> predicate)
    {
        //var results = States.Where(function);
        var results = States.Where(predicate);

        var blah = new TimeSpan(results.Select(x => x.TimeSpan).Sum(x => x.Ticks));

        return blah;
    }
    public double PercentDownTime;
}
```

In this case you would need to pass a matching predicate in your `Main`:

```
var TotalTimeNotRunning = testData.TotalTimeWhere(x => x.State.IsRunning == false);

var TotalTimeIsAlarmed = testData2.TotalTimeWhere(x => x.State.IsAlarmed == true);
```

Comment: That gets me in the right direction. Is it possible to have the predicate act on State, only. So that I can do TotalTimeWhere(x => x.IsRunning == false); ?

Comment: @TheColonel26 Yes, sure. Please, see the updated answer :)

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the comments and other answers, `Func<T, bool>` cannot be used *directly* as predicate for `IEnumerable<StateOverTime<T>>`, which requires `Func<StateOverTime<T>, bool>`.

However the later can easily be composed by applying the passed `Func` to `StateOverTime<T>.State` property like this:

```
var results = States.Where(sot => predicate(sot.State));
```